# Calculation of month and year based on duration

Tags: javascript

Available data: month, year, duration.  Need to iterate through the month for the given duration and must find out the month at the given duration.

For example,
If the selected month is Mar 2015 and duration is 4, the result should be Nov 2014 - that is 4 months before to the selected month.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is perfect for this:

```
var yourDateObject = new Date;
var fourMonthsAgo = moment(yourDateObject).subtract(4, 'months');
```

and if your dates are formatted like "Mar 2015" you can simply do `var yourDateObject = moment('Mar 2015')`

Comment: I dont have a date. I should iterate only with month.

Comment: so you can do `var yourDateObject = moment('Mar 2015')` right?

Comment: Ya fine that should work. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
function timeMachine(oldDate, n){
   var d = new Date(oldDate);
   d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + n);
   return d;
}
```

Where the parameter **n** is the number of months, use a negative value to substract, it's plain JavaScript no need to install other libraries.

Example:

```
timeMachine('Mar 2015', -4);
```

Comment: nit-picking here but calling a function m is sort of sketchy, we don't want googlers c&ping that into their code!

Comment: We're not here to give people code to copy, but to let them understand how to solve their problems in a specific programming language, rather than using a library, especially with such a basic function :)

Comment: I agree, but googlers are going to google. Plus you totally missed an opportunity to call your function something cool, like timeTraveller or something.

Comment: You've got a point! the name has beed changed.